# Apply Function to Every Row in pandas DataFrame Using Multiple Column Values as Parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a pandas `DataFrame` with multiple columns

```
pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Alice'], 'age': [20, 40], 'height': [2.0, 2.1]})

    name  age  height
0    Bob   20     2.0
1  Alice   40     2.1
```

And a function that takes multiple parameters

```
def example_hash(name: str, age: int) -> str:
    return "In 10 years {} will be {}".format(name, age+10)
```

**How can the DataFrame be updated with an additional column which contains the result of applying a function to a subset of the other columns?**

The resulting DataFrame would be the result of applying `example_hash` to the `name` & `age` columns:

```
    name  age  height                            hash
0    Bob   20     2.0     In 10 years Bob would be 30
1  Alice   40     2.1    In 10 years Alice will be 50
```

**I'm interested in a `pandas` centric response.**  I understand that it's possible to construct a python `list`, iterate over the rows, and append to the list which would eventually become the column.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Isn't apply what you are looking for? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without changing your `example_hash()` method:

#### Just use [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```
In [2204]: import numpy as np 

In [2200]: def example_hash(name: str, age: int) -> str: 
      ...:     return "In 10 years {} will be {}".format(name, age+10) 
      ...:                                    
In [2202]: df['new'] = np.vectorize(example_hash)(df['name'], df['age'])                                                                                                                                    

In [2203]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2203]: 
    name  age  height                           new
0    Bob   20     2.0    In 10 years Bob will be 30
1  Alice   40     2.1  In 10 years Alice will be 50
```

#### OR use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `lambda` like this without changing your custom method:

```
In [2207]: df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: example_hash(x['name'], x['age']), axis=1)                                                                                                                        

In [2208]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2208]: 
    name  age  height                           new
0    Bob   20     2.0    In 10 years Bob will be 30
1  Alice   40     2.1  In 10 years Alice will be 50
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `apply` function to iterate over the rows and add a new column.

```
In [139]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Alice'], 'age': [20, 40], 'height': [2.0, 2.1]})

In [140]: df
Out[140]:
    name  age  height
0    Bob   20     2.0
1  Alice   40     2.1


In [142]: def example_hash(row):
     ...:     row['hash']= "In 10 years {} will be {}".format(row['name'], row['age']+10)
     ...:     return row
     ...:

In [143]: df = df.apply(example_hash,axis=1)

In [144]: df
Out[144]:
    name  age  height                          hash
0    Bob   20     2.0    In 10 years Bob will be 30
1  Alice   40     2.1  In 10 years Alice will be 50
```